# Facter does not show custom Puppet facts

Tags: puppet, facter

`facter` does not show the custom facts while Puppetboard does.

According to [this source](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/list-facter-facts.html) the paramater `-p` is required to show all facts including the custom once. I have tried it but the outcome seems to be identical to the outcome of `facter`.

I tried `facter --custom-dir=/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter` and it results in: `invalid option: --custom-dir=/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter`

The question is why facter does not show custom puppet facts and how to solve this issue?

Comment: According to puppet doc you need to specify `--custom-dir` to see all the facts..  `facter --custom-dir=<custom_fact_dir>`

Comment: Here is the link : http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/custom_facts.html#loading-custom-facts

Comment: I guess you can try exporting the fact load path `export LOAD_PATH=$LOAD_PATH:your_custom_path`  and give a try

Comment: @chetangb Thank you for the advices. I have updated the question.

Comment: Try: `facter -p --debug`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from `facter --help`:

> -p, --puppet                     (Deprecated: use `puppet facts` instead) Load the Puppet libraries, thus allowing Facter to load Puppet-specific facts.

With current versions of puppet you can see all the facts with this. You may need to tell it the path to the modules for it to be able to pick up any custom facts from them. eg:

```
puppet facts --basemodulepath /path/to/modules:/path/to/other/modules
```